# How to use ng2-cordova-oauth to Sign in Firebase V3 by exchanging token

Tags: cordova, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am having a tough time to use the access token got from ng2-cordova-oauth to request sign in Firebase. This [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) here is not clear. Here is my code.

```
loginUser(): any {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let token: any;
  let fullData: any;
  const oauth = new CordovaOauth();
  const provider = new Google({
    clientId: "[CLIENT ID]",
    appScope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube", "email"]
  })

  return oauth.logInVia(provider).then(success => {

      console.log(success);

      let jString = JSON.stringify(success);
      let tokenObj = JSON.parse(jString); 

      token = tokenObj.access_token;
      let headers = new Headers();
      let googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings%2C+snippet%2C+id%2C+statistics&mine=true";
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this.http.get(googleAPI, { headers })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {

          console.log(data);

          fullData = {
            uid: data.items[0].id,
            photoURL: data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url,
            name: data.items[0].snippet.title,
            youtube_channel : data
          }

          let googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);

          return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential).then((firebaseSuccess) => {
              console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(firebaseSuccess));
              return this.userProfile.child(fullData.uid).update(fullData).then(_ => {
                resolve(fullData);
              });
          })
        })


  }, (error) => {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
  }); 
});
}
```

So the code gets the `access_token` from ng2-cordova-oauth which is no problem. Then using the token to get some YouTube scope info. Also no problem. Then I need the exchange the `access_token` with Firebase using `googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);` which keep giving me 400 bad request.

I am using Ionic 2 and deploy on xcode on my iphone for testing. So Firebase doc said the handling Google signin manually is from a `id_token` from a Google user. But the token I got from ng2-cordova-oauth works and it is a Google token. Is this the token I need for Firebase? Very confusing. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

With Google credentials, the first parameter is the google id token. The second parameter is the access token.
Try the following:
firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token);